# Adding an entity without knowing the parent id

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to insert a new entity without knowing it's PK. The parent entity has another property which is a guid and unique which is what we use to do cross db references and this is all I have. I have done it in the past but can't find a reference on how to do it again.

```
    [Table("School")]
    public class SchoolEntity
    {
        public SchoolEntity()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<StudentEntity>();
        }


        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
        public virtual ICollection<StudentEntity> Students { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Student")]
    public class StudentEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
    }


    //ExternalId won't work cause is not the primary key.
    var school = new School { ExternalId = Guid.Parse('68e05258-550a-40f3-b68a-5d27a0d825a0') };

    context.Attach(school);
    context.Schools.Add.Add(new Student());
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The key is set up as an Identity column so EF will get the ID automatically from the DB when the entity is saved. If you are adding a student to the school, simply add it to the school's students collection and EF will take care of the FK assignments automatically. (Provided the relationship is mapped correctly.)

Comment: @StevePy I only have the externalId which is not the primary key. I can obviously add the new entity to the collection or retrieve the parent from the database as Ivan said but I wan't to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the PK of the referenced entity is *required* in order to set properly the FK of the referencing entity.

If you don't have it, apparently you should find it (get it from the database) based on what you have (secondary identifier in your case). For instance:

```
var school = context.Schools.Single(e => e.ExternalId == externalId);

var student = new Student { School = school, ... };

context.Students.Add(student);
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

There is no way to get that working without fetching. If you don't want to fetch the whole referenced entity (and you are sure it's not tracked by the context), then you can fetch the PK only and `Attach` a stub entity:

```
var schoolId = context.Schools.Where(e => e.ExternalId == externalId)
    .Select(e => e.Id).Single();
var school = new School( Id = schoolId);
context.Attach(school);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan but that requires me to fetch the entity which is not an option. I remember having done it without the need to get the entity from the db, not sure if it was with EF extensions... thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not possible w/o fetching. If you don't want to fetch the whole entity, the minimum is to fetch it's PK and then `Attach`. I'll update the answer with that option.

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible to insert an entity whose id is equal to the result of a query being executed dynamically all in one database call? That's odd because I think I really did it a while ago, but I guess you're right. Thanks

Comment: The related entity does not have to be attached to the context if you expose the FK property.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro True, but OP does not expose it (and there isn't a *requirement* to expose FKs in model). And attach or not, the key is that it has to be fetched :)